# Locate an iOS app or folder

Tags: ios

I would like to write an app that would let a user locate an app or folder.

For example a user would like to find: **Widget**

The app would return:

- The **Widget** app is located on screen 4 < in the **Thingamagigs** folder >

or

- The **Widget** folder is located on screen 4

What commands would I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in iOS 5, there is no public API that would give you access to this information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that functionality is available in the iOS SDK, App's are pretty much sandboxed and unable to do very much at all with information about other apps.

(Also, why not just use the search feature of iOS?)

Comment: The Search feature shows you hits out of context. You have to search next time too, since you don't learn which folder something is in.

But yeah, you won't be able to get at Springboard info.